# Custom validation email address if checkbox not equal value in Contact Form 7 in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to enable email address verification if a specific checkbox is selected. If not selected, then let the form run normally. I use this method ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67894173/15671888)) to validate the email address.

My form

```
     <label>[text* your-name placeholder"First name*"] </label>
        <label>[text* last-name placeholder"Last name*"] </label>
        <label> [email* email-799 id:emailvalid placeholder"Work email*"] </label>
        <label>[intl_tel tel-phone placeholder"Phone number*"] </label>    
   [checkbox* checkbox-999 use_label_element exclusive id:c_b "Hire full-time employees" "Manager" "Set up" "Partner" "I'm a freelancer" ]
```

My php where I try to make a check that it doesn't equal *I'm a freelancer*

```
function custom_email_validation_filter($result, $tag)
{
    $field_name = 'email-799';
    $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode($tag);
    $frelancer = isset( $_POST['checkbox-999'] ) ? trim( $_POST['checkbox-999'] ) : '';
    if ($field_name == $tag->name && $frelancer !== "I'm a freelancer" ) {
        $the_value = isset($_POST[$field_name]) ? trim($_POST[$field_name]) : "";
        if (!is_business_email($the_value)) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, "Please enter a valid business email");
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, I share the solution

```
 function custom_email_validation_filter_en($result, $tag)
    {
        if ( isset($_POST['_wpcf7']) && $_POST['_wpcf7'] == 7274) {
        $field_name = 'email-799';
        $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode($tag);
        $frelancer = isset( $_POST['checkbox-999'] ) ? trim( $_POST['checkbox-999'] ) : '';
        if(isset($_POST['checkbox-999'])){
        if ($field_name == $tag->name) {
            $the_value = isset($_POST[$field_name]) ? trim($_POST[$field_name]) : "";
             if($_POST['checkbox-999'] !== "I\'m a freelancer"){    
            if (!my_business_email($the_value)) {
                $result->invalidate($tag, "Please enter a valid business email");
            }}
        return $result;
    }}
    }
         return $result;
    }
```